# React reducer works, but once going through the web-page becomes undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

By some reason when i load a page for the first time, the reducer function and state executes correctly and you can access the data, however. Once you switched to another page, and then go back to previous it says that state is undefined. Here is the image

[image]

The code in the following file looks like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Hook from "../../hooks/display";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import * as actionTypes from "../../store/actions";

import "./main.css";

class Main extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.props.stateName);
    this.props.console_inside();
    console.log("hey");
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div>
        <h1>The container view (page)</h1>
        <Hook />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    stateName: state.inside_reducer
  };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    console_inside: () => dispatch({ type: actionTypes.DO_SOMETHING_1 })
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Main);
```

and in my reducer.js

```
import * as actionTypes from "./actions";

const initialState = {
  persons: [],
  inside_reducer: "I am inside of a reducer"
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.DO_SOMETHING_1:
      console.log(state.inside_reducer);
      return 1;
    case actionTypes.DO_SOMETHING_2:
      return 1;
  }
  return state;
};

export default reducer;
```

> The questions would be

1) Why does it say undefined on the second time you enter the page?

> P.S: not sure if its important but just in case the problem is here
>   In my index.js

```
import * as serviceWorker from "./serviceWorker";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { createStore } from "redux";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from "./store/reducer";

const store = createStore(reducer);

const app = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </Provider>
);
ReactDOM.render(app, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Answer to question #1, would be to put `console.log('hey') inside of componentDidMount() that solves the problem of excessive execution, but whatssup with undefined when u go through the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never return your state

```
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.DO_SOMETHING_1:
      console.log(state.inside_reducer);
      return state ; // <==== You must return your state instead of 1
    case actionTypes.DO_SOMETHING_2:
      return state ; // <==== You must return your state instead of 1
  }
  return state;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly sure this is because you're setting your state to be 1, rather than returning whatever you want the new state to be!

1.inside_reducer will, indeed, be undefined.

A reducer returns the new state, so you're overriding it. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but try something along the lines of

```
return {
  ...state,
  inside_reducer: 'reduced'
}
```

instead in both your case conditions.